# error use of undeclared identifier 'mainwindow' semantic issue in QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator

I just create new Qt Widgets Application. I open the mainwindow.cpp and it's like mainwindow.cpp doesnt see the "mainwindow.h" while i was on editor. But compiler works fine. How do i fix this semantic issues?

I added 'QT += widgets' to .pro file. It doesnt work.

These are actually default files.

--mainwindow.h--

[image: mainwindow.h]

--mainwindow.cpp--

[image: mainwindow.cpp]

Comment: what message is displaying the QTcreator qhe you mouse over it?

Comment: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MainWindow'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed this bug by unchecking Help/Plugins/C++/ClangCodeModel and restart QtCreator.